# reading properly docx files in python

Tags: python, docx

I have been trying to read docx files, but with no succes in python. The problem is that it deletes the numbers at the beginning of my lines for some reason.

```
text = docx2txt.process("X.docx")
text_new = text.replace('\n\n',"\n")

text_new.split('\n')
```

Does anyone have suggestion why it happens?

This is the output:

```
['1. melléklet a 36/2018. (XI. 13.) MNB rendelethez',

 '',

 'A pénz- és hitelpiaci szervezetek felügyeleti jelentéseire vonatkozó általános kitöltési előírások',

 '',

 '',

 'Kapcsolódó jogszabályok',

 '\ta Magyar Export-Import Bank Részvénytársaságról és a Magyar Exporthitel Biztosító Részvénytársaságról szóló 1994. évi XLII. törvény
```

Instead of this, the output should include a number '1.' before `'Kapcsolódó jogszabályok'` and should not say `\ta`.

Comment: Can you show how does the `.docx` look like ?

Comment: I would guess that this is an enumeration that is just *rendered* as "1." but internally is stored differently.

Comment: yes, it is an enumeration. I just did not copy the whole output. Do you have any recommendation?